# Windows Explorer: how did they do this?

Tags: com, windows-explorer, com+

can somebody explain what technique they used to do this? See the yellow area:

[image: Windows Explorer has a new area with custom behavior]

it looks like a totally new panel, programmed from scratch. I need to do the same: add custom areas to Windows Explorer, containing an advanced file manager. I'd like to know what technology this is (in particular, what COM interfaces do you need to implement? IDockingWindow?); where the documentation is (not just the reference but an introduction); and if there are source code samples. Thank you

Comment: Probably the same thing that was done for the Control Panel, where there is both a Namespace Extension (that allows it to appear in the TreeView) and *something* that determines how it's displayed. I don't know how this something is called, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is NSE and it creates its own implementation of IShellView.